Oh no! Something has gone wrong error when upgrading
While updating Ubuntu, my computer shut down. When I turned it on again, I encountered this error. I looked at various solutions, but none of them worked. I can't exit this screen. Alt + Ctrl + F2 doesn't work either. When I turn on the computer to go to Recovery mode, I press Shift + Esc, but then it takes me to the GNU GRUB 2.06 screen.


Can you boot using any of the options on the grub menu?
